# How can i solve the 406 error, “Could not find acceptable representation”?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a service that receive a requests from an API and with the headers make another request to other API. With the data of the second API, it's done a mapping and then we respond with these data.
During the develop I found this error and I cant solve it. I cant respond with the right JSON to mi first API.

My code is simple altough is disordered. I've a controller and a model file

controller

```
@RestController
public class controller {


//Request of global API
@RequestMapping(value="orches", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method=RequestMethod.GET)

public model globalrequest(
        @RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String Auth,
        @RequestHeader(value="X-Country") String Country,
        @RequestHeader(value="X-Global-Id") String LocalClid) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {


    // Country testing
    String localApiUrl="";
    switch (Country) {
    case "SPA":
        localApiUrl = "https://myapilocal";
    default:
        //error
    };


    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    //Request of Local API   
    //header
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("X-IBM-Client-Id", LocalClid);
    headers.set("Authorization", Auth);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);


    //Send the request as GET
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(localApiUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    //System.out.println(response);
    String body = response.getBody();
    return new model(body);

}
```

On the other side is the model

model

```
public class model {

 private static String myJson = null;
ProfileGlo profileGlo = new ProfileGlo();
 public model(String body) throws JsonProcessingException  {
        //super();
        ProfileLoc profileLoc = new Gson().fromJson(body, ProfileLoc.class);
        mapping(profileGlo, profileLoc);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        myJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(profileGlo);    
        System.out.println(myJson);
        System.out.println(profileGlo.customerBasicData.customerNameData.firstName);
     }  

public static void mapping(ProfileGlo profileGlo, ProfileLoc profileLoc) {

    if ( profileLoc.personType.equals("F"))  {
        // Mapping of the type of person
        profileGlo.customerType = "1";
        // Mapping of the Name
        profileGlo.customerBasicData.customerNameData.firstName = profileLoc.fullName.getName();
        //Mapping of the lastNames
        profileGlo.customerBasicData.customerNameData.middleName = profileLoc.fullName.getLastName();
        //Mapping companyName
        profileGlo.sMEBusinessCustomerBasicData.companyName = null;
        //Mapping birthDate
        profileGlo.customerBasicData.birthDate = profileLoc.birthDate;      
    }
    else if ( profileLoc.personType.equals("J")) {
        // Mapping of the type of person
        profileGlo.customerType = "2";
        // Mapping of the Name
        profileGlo.sMEBusinessCustomerBasicData.companyName = profileLoc.fullName.getName();
        //Mapping of the lastNames
        profileGlo.customerBasicData.customerNameData.middleName = null;
        //Mapping companyName
        profileGlo.sMEBusinessCustomerBasicData.companyName = profileLoc.fullName.getCompanyName();
        //Mapping birthDate
        profileGlo.customerBasicData.birthDate = null;

    }       
    else {
            //error500
    }

}

@ResponseBody
public String orches(HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  response.setStatus(200);
  return myJson;
}
```

}

Also there are the ProfileGlo and ProfileLoc objects that they are defined but I dont include here because there is no sense.
I need to know how I can give response to the first API, since I dont get the 406 error.

Comment: Why are you wrapping up the model instead of simply returning the `body` as the method result? Look through the Spring Getting Started guides for examples on REST controllers--it looks like you're trying to handle a lot of pieces by hand (like content-type and HTTP status) that Spring does automatically. (Additionally, it will be much easier to read your code if you follow Java conventions such as naming your classes `GlobalRequest`.)

Comment: I am wrapping up the model becouse the response that I have to give to the first API is diferent of the body.

Answer (score 0):

1. your second API will throw back the HTTP error directly 406 error and the first api will need to handle it because its the client of the first api.
2. If you want to design a json you could create a Error object and use code and description to communicate between first and second api like so

`class Error {
     private String error;
     private String description;
}`

Comment: But the error is of the first API? Isnt it?. Other than that thanks for the recommendation